# PHP SQL server extensions broken

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, php-extension

I'm trying to get PHP talking to MS SQL server by following [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is for SQL server 2005 (I'm using 2014 express but it was the most recent I could find).

I'm running 32bit Wamp and PHP 5.5.12. I have installed `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` in the `ext` folder and have added the following lines to `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

All seems to go smoothly but no SQLSRV information is listed under `phpinfo()` and on the `php extensions` tab for Wamp they are listed but with a red triangle containing an exclamation mark next to them.

Anyone know what I've missed?

Comment: PDO is the solution man

Comment: MSSQL is no longer supported. Use SQLSRV or PDO.

Comment: To previous commenters: the question is about SQLSRV, which 1) is the only supported extension for Windows and 2) it does provide a PDO driver

Comment: I suggest you run PHP from the command line. It's often the only reliable way to see certain startup errors.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: do you mean launch `phpinfo()` from command line?

Comment: I assume you are using Windows. Hit the "Windows" key in your keyboard, type "cmd" and click on the "cmd.exe" result. You should get a black Windows with a bliking cursor. Type "php" (without the quotes) and hit enter.

Comment: Strange - from command line, if I run the file: `php info.php` I get lots of info including `sqlsrv support => enabled` but if I just type `php` cmd line hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just type `php` at the command line it waits for more input, it does not hang.

If when you run php from the command line ( PHP CLI ) you see sqlsrv is supported but not when you run phpinfo through Apache, then you have edited the wrong `php.ini` file. There are normally 2, one to control PHP CLI and one to control PHP when being run under Apache.

The `php.ini` that controls php under apache is normally in the `\apache\bin` folder. The exact path is of course dependant upon whether you use WAMPServer/XAMPP... or install everything yourself.

Comment: Ah, well that explains why following the instruction "Type "php" (without the quotes) and hit enter" gives the impression that it was hanging. =)

Comment: Anyway, yes I had edited the wrong `php.ini` file. +1 and thanks.